# Calling Restful service through jQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, rest, jquery

I am trying to access a restful web service using jQuery Ajax but getting following error:  
**XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{cefa3a59-2437-454f-b39a-384cf1fdf072} Line Number 1, Column 1:**

This how I am making the call:

```
function getResponse(){
       $.ajax( {
       type:'Get',
       dataType:'xml',
       url:'http://localhost:8080/RestTest/restservice/number',
       success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
     }
   } );
}
```

Here my response data type is xml.  
I understand that there is some cross domain issue but not sure how to resolve it. Please help me on this.

Comment: What is the domain of the page the script is on?

Comment: It sounds like the XML is invalid. If you directly access the `url` do you get valid XML?

Comment: @abraham Yes browser is printing the xml properly and I am getting the response while making the request using restful test tools.

Comment: @gideon script is in local machine itself.

Comment: I am also  facing the same issue ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565584/how-to-cal-resttemplate-web-service-using-jquery. If you have solution means, share to me

Comment: same problem... did you solve it?

Comment: Yes. Please refer the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
dataType: 'json',
data: data,
success: callback
});
```